# Wrong return type on IEnumerator method (AsyncOperation.progress)

Tags: unity, c#

I am basically just using this script from the documentation as it's the exact same thing that I want to do.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-progress.html

Just replacing it with my own buttons and scene number but I get the error:

```
CS0407: 'IEnumerator MenuController.LoadScene()' has the wrong return type
```

What should be done differently?

```
public class MenuController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button StartButton;
    public Text EasyButtonText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartButton.onClick.AddListener(LoadScene);
    }

    IEnumerator LoadScene()
    {
        yield return null;

        //Begin to load the Scene you specify
        AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
        //Don't let the Scene activate until you allow it to
        asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;
        Debug.Log("Pro :" + asyncOperation.progress);
        //When the load is still in progress, output the Text and progress bar
        while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
        {
            //Output the current progress
            EasyButtonText.text = "Loading progress: " + (asyncOperation.progress * 100) + "%";

            // Check if the load has finished
            if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.9f)
            {
                //Change the Text to show the Scene is ready
                EasyButtonText.text = "Press space";
                //Wait to you press the space key to activate the Scene
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                    //Activate the Scene
                    asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cut out this part of the sample:

```
void LoadButton()
{
    //Start loading the Scene asynchronously and output the progress bar
    StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
}
```

The button's `onClick` event can only work with methods that match the signature it's looking for, specifically:

```
void SomeFunctionName() { ... }
```

No return value, no arguments.

But your `LoadScene` method is a coroutine, with a signature that looks like:

```
 IEnumerator SomeCoroutineName(...) { ... }
```

So it doesn't match. Moreover, to get the benefit of resuming a coroutine after it's `yield`ed, you have to start it via `StartCoroutine()`.

That's what `LoadButton()` does above. It acts as an adapter, providing a listener function that can be attached to the button's `onClick` event, and then doing the work of starting the coroutine.

So `StartButton.onClick.AddListener(LoadScene);` should be `StartButton.onClick.AddListener(LoadButton);` using the method from the sample.

When copying code from the Internet, make sure you didn't accidentally delete anything - it might have been important!

Comment: Wow can't believe I didn't see it.. thanks